# Angular lazy loading deprecated - is it usable?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have an angular 9 project and I'm using the string representation of lazy loading like

```
{
  path: 'lazy',
  loadChildren: './modules/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule',
}
```

Though I'm not getting error, I think this does not actually apply lazy loading.

So should I update it to the new `import('./modules/lazy/lazy.module')` format? Or the string representation works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check the lazy loading capabilities, you can check the dist folder and if you find several modules then it is still lazy loaded. However, the new syntax provides a more convenient way to create lazy loaded modules since you have the tslineter to help and you can move around freely from module to others.

This article provides a good way of migration from string representation to the new syntax https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/automatically-upgrade-lazy-loaded-angular-modules-for-ivy-e760872e6084

Answer (score 0):

{
path: 'lazy',
loadChildren: () => import('./modules/lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)
}
**like [this link](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)**

Comment: Thanks, but actually I wanted to know can I use the string method? I found out how to do it but I want to make sure that I have to change this in my project or not